# Using AWSS3TransferUtility to upload data on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've managed to successfully upload data using the AWS 2.0 SDK, however I'm having some trouble understanding the "re-wiring" of completion handlers that is meant to take place on resuming of the app.

What I believe I should be doing, is at comment 6, saving the upload task. Then if it reaches the completionHandler block, deleting it. However, if the app is terminated before this, I can look at my saved upload tasks in the block at comment 4. Any saved tasks would be "re-wired" to the completion handler.

For reference, imagine this code happening in an "Upload" class, and in a block, which is the "uploadSuccess()" code you see in the completionHandler.

For reference [here is the blog that introduced the AWSS3TransferUtility](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx283AGGIL76PKP/Amazon-S3-Transfer-Utility-for-iOS), and [here is its documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transferutility.html).

Hopefully someone can guide me on this.

```
// 1. Get/Setup credentials

AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"IdentityPoolId"];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

// 2. Create AWSS3 Transfer blocks

AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression *expression = [AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression new];
expression.uploadProgress = ^(AWSS3TransferUtilityTask *task, int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Do something e.g. Update a progress bar.
    });
};

AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock completionHandler = ^(AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *task, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Do something e.g. Alert a user for transfer completion.
        // On failed uploads, `error` contains the error object.
        if (error) {
            uploadSuccess(NO);

        } else {
            uploadSuccess(YES);
        }
    });
};

// 3. Create Transfer Utility

AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];

// 4. Rewire Transfer Utility blocks

[transferUtility
     enumerateToAssignBlocksForUploadTask:^(AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *uploadTask, __autoreleasing AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadProgressBlock *uploadProgressBlockReference, __autoreleasing AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock *completionHandlerReference) {
         NSLog(@"Upload task identifier = %lu", (unsigned long)uploadTask.taskIdentifier);

         // Use `uploadTask.taskIdentifier` to determine what blocks to assign.

         //*uploadProgressBlockReference = // Reassign your progress feedback block.
         *completionHandlerReference = completionHandler;// Reassign your completion handler.
     }
     downloadTask:^(AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadTask *downloadTask, __autoreleasing AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadProgressBlock *downloadProgressBlockReference, __autoreleasing AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock *completionHandlerReference) {
     }];

// 5. Upload data using Transfer Utility

[[transferUtility uploadData:myNSDataObject
                      bucket:@"bucketName"
                         key:@"keyName"
                 contentType:@"text/plain"
                  expression:expression
            completionHander:completionHandler] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
    }
    if (task.exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", task.exception);
    }
    if (task.result) {
        AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *uploadTask = task.result; 
        // 6. Should i be saving uploadTasks here?
    }

    return nil;
}];
```

Comment: You should take a look at this [sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3BackgroundTransfer-Sample/Objective-C). The sample has only one upload task, so it is not saving `taskIdentifier`. However, you can save it in "6" and use it in `- enumerateToAssignBlocksForUploadTask:` to determine which blocks belong to which task.